# Does Elastic-sink connector in Confluent Platform work with elastic cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I tried a simple example with elastic-sink connector in Confluent Platform version 6.2 and I observed that if I connect my elastic-sink connector with elasticsearch in local(http://192.168.x.x:9200) it works well, but if I use my elasticsearch cloud the conenctor fails. So as far as I understood the elastic-sink connector that I use in Confluent Platform does not work with elastic cloud, right? Should I use Confluent Cloud if I want to connect my elastic-sink connector to Elastic Cloud?
The example is the follow: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/overview.html

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783936/unable-to-connect-elastic-sink-connector-to-elasticsearch-with-confluent-platfor The simple answer is that as long as your client version supports the server's expected, compatible versions of the Elasticsearch api protocol, then you can use any Elasticsearch server... The error in that question `ParsingException[Failed to parse object: expecting field with name [error] but found` - it is related to the JSON response handling, and if you searched for the error, you'd find it's a versioning issue

Comment: In any case, based on the partnership announcement, it should work https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-and-confluent-partner-to-deliver-an-enhanced-kafka-elasticsearch-experience

Comment: I don't think that is a versioning issue. I ran the same example with my local elasticsearch with the same version of my elastic cloud and it works. From your link I saw that Elastic Cloud works well with Confluent Cloud. My question is: does elastic cloud work weel also with confluent platform?

Comment: Confluent Cloud is just a hosted version of Confluent Platform. There should be minimal differences and the Kafka Connect code definitely isn't any different

Comment: I have working example of elastic search sink connector - https://github.com/vishaldhanani/Elastic-Search-Sink-Connector